# Django rest framework is not logging in the non superusers after calling user model to the serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to get user data with get method in api but when I used custom user model its is not logging in logginf this error 
`{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "No active account found with the given credentials"
    ]
}`

how can i handle this? only the super user in loggin in rest of the users are not loggin in

serializer.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name','username','password','email')
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CurrentUserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router.register('Users',views.CurrentUserView)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'languages',
'corsheaders']

MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
)}
```

Comment: How did you get this error ?

Comment: What is your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in `REST_FRAMEWORK` from settings?

Comment: `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}`

Comment: i added them now take a look